# Where to store relative dropdown options and their associated program logic in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture

I have time periods (`terms`) and things happening during those periods (`events`). When I list events I would like the user to be able to specify a **relative** date range e.g. From "the start of term" for "one month" or from "today" for "one week". The reason for relative is so that if they change their preferred range we can remember that in a cookie or session variable and calculate the absolute dates on the fly the next day or week that they visit.

I got it working but the options and their logic are scattered (settings file x 2 x 2 and also in term_decorator) plus I'm specifying them as an array of arrays only because that is what I initially needed in the view for the dropdown.

I would like to store the options (including which is the default option for each type) with a little bit more structure (a class? a struct? a hash?), store the logic with the options (using a proc? a lambda?) and wrap that all in something sensible (a helper class? helper method(s)? some sort of constant?).

The wrapping object can tell the view what the possible options are, tell the helper method what the possible options are (so it can validate the proposed option), tell the view which option is selected and tell the decorator the logic it needs to convert the relative date into an absolute date.

Is there a Ruby or Rails idiom for what I'm trying to achieve? Is this a sane approach to the problem? If yes to both of those, what constructs do I use to assemble the components and what do I use to wrap it all together?

Any help is appreciated as I fear I have bitten off more than I can chew!

#### My thoughts so far

To store the options I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------+
|      id       |       description       | from_or_for | default? | calculation (proc? lambda?) |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------+
| start_of_term | 'The start of the term' | from        | no       | object.term.starts_on       |
| today         | 'Today'                 | from        | yes      | Date.today                  |
| tomorrow      | 'Tomorrow'              | from        | no       | Date.tomorrow               |
| one_week      | 'One week'              | for         | yes      | starts + 1.week             |
| one_month     | 'One month'             | for         | no       | starts + 1.month            |
| rest_of_term  | 'The rest of the term'  | for         | no       | object.term.ends_on         |
+---------------+-------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

Or maybe instead of having the from_or_for column I should group the forms and fors into an array each inside the wrapping object?

#### My previous (scattered) solution

**config/settings.yaml:**

```
...
events:
  from_date_options: [['The start of Term', 'start_of_term'], ['One Week Ago', 'one_week_ago'], ['Beginning of Week', 'start_of_week'], ['Today', 'today'], ['Tomorrow', 'tomorrow'], ['Start of Next Week', 'start_of_next_week']]
  for_duration_options: [['One day', 'one_day'], ['One week', 'one_week'], ['One month', 'one_month'], ['The rest of the Term', 'rest_of_term']]
  default_from: 'today'
  default_for: 'one_week'
...
```

**app/helpers/events_helper.rb:**

```
...
def validate_range_option(key)
  valid_options = case key
  when 'from'
    Settings.events.from_date_options.collect {|arr| arr[1]}
  when 'for'
    Settings.events.for_duration_options.collect {|arr| arr[1]}
  else
    nil
  end

  param = params[key]
  cookie = cookies["events_#{key}"]

  if param.present? && param.in?(valid_options)
    cookies["events_#{key}"] = param
    return param
  elsif cookie.present? && cookie.in?(valid_options)
    return cookie
  else
    return Settings.events.send("default_#{key}")
  end
end
...
```

**app/decorators/term_decorator.rb:**

```
...
def get_events(from_date:, for_duration:, show_all: false)
  starts = case from_date
  when 'start_of_term'
    object.term.starts_on #include pre-term if set???
  when 'one_week_ago'
    Date.today - 1.week
  when 'start_of_week'
    Date.today.beginning_of_week
  when 'today'
    Date.today
  when 'tomorrow'
    Date.tomorrow
  when 'start_of_next_week'
    Date.today.beginning_of_week + 1.week
  else
    Date.today
  end

  finishes = case for_duration
  when 'one_day'
    starts
  when 'one_week'
    starts + 1.week
  when 'one_month'
    starts + 1.month
  when 'rest_of_term'
    object.term.ends_on #include post-term if set???
  else
    Date.today + 1.week
  end

  if helpers.term_manager? || show_all
    object.events_between(starts, finishes).order(:starts_at)
  else
    helpers.current_user.term_events_between(object, starts, finishes).sort{ |x,y| x.starts_at <=> y.starts_at }
  end
end
...
```

**app/views/events/index.haml:**

```
- validated_from_date = validate_range_option('from')
- validated_for_duration = validate_range_option('for')

= form_for url_for(permitted_link_params), :html => { :class => 'form-inline pull-right', method: 'GET' } do |f|
  .form-group
    %label
      %strong From
    = select_tag(:from, options_for_select(Settings.events.from_date_options, validated_from_date))
  .form-group
    %label
      %strong For
    = select_tag(:for, options_for_select(Settings.events.for_duration_options, validated_for_duration))

  = f.submit 'Go', :class => 'btn btn-success'

- events = term.get_events(from_date: validated_from_date, for_duration: validated_for_duration, show_all: true)
- if events.present?
...
```

Comment: If your arrays aren't mean to be edited in the future I'd make them constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've come up with so far is to put the options and all their associated data into an array of hashes stored in a constant and then provide some helper methods to get it all back out again.

There's probably a more Ruby-like way to get the values out then using `.map`, I'm all ears if anyone has specific or overall suggestions!

**events_helper.rb**

```
RANGE_OPTIONS = [ {id: 'start_of_term', description: 'Beginning of term', from_or_for: 'from', default: false, logic: "object.term.starts_on"},
                  {id: 'one_week_ago', description: 'One week ago', from_or_for: 'from', default: false, logic: "Date.today - 1.week"},
                  {id: 'start_of_week', description: 'Beginning of week', from_or_for: 'from', default: false, logic: "Date.today.beginning_of_week"},
                  {id: 'today', description: 'Today', from_or_for: 'from', default: true, logic: "Date.today"},
                  {id: 'tomorrow', description: 'Tomorrow', from_or_for: 'from', default: false, logic: "Date.tomorrow"},
                  {id: 'start_of_next_week', description: 'Start of next week', from_or_for: 'from', default: false, logic: "Date.today.beginning_of_week + 1.week"},
                  {id: 'one_day', description: 'One day', from_or_for: 'for', default: false, logic: "starts"},
                  {id: 'one_week', description: 'One week', from_or_for: 'for', default: true, logic: "starts + 1.week"},
                  {id: 'one_month', description: 'One month', from_or_for: 'for', default: false, logic: "starts + 1.month"},
                  {id: 'rest_of_term', description: 'The rest of the term', from_or_for: 'for', default: false, logic: "object.term.ends_on"}
                ]

def date_options_array(from_or_for)
  RANGE_OPTIONS.map { |o| [o[:description], o[:id]] if o[:from_or_for] == from_or_for }.compact
end

def date_option_ids(from_or_for)
  RANGE_OPTIONS.map { |o| o[:id] if o[:from_or_for] == from_or_for }.compact
end

def default_date_option(from_or_for)
  RANGE_OPTIONS.map { |o| o[:id] if o[:from_or_for] == from_or_for && o[:default] }.compact.first
end

def option_logic(option_id)
  RANGE_OPTIONS.map { |o| o[:logic] if o[:id] == option_id }.compact.first
end

def validate_range_option(from_or_for)
  valid_options = date_option_ids(from_or_for)

  param = params[from_or_for]
  cookie = cookies["coco_events_#{from_or_for}"]

  option = ''
  if param.present? && param.in?(valid_options)
    cookies["coco_events_#{from_or_for}"] = param
    option = param
  elsif cookie.present? && cookie.in?(valid_options)
    option = cookie
  else
    option = default_date_option(from_or_for)
  end
  return {id: option, logic: option_logic(option)}
end
```

**term_decorator.rb** no longer knows about specific options and gets a lot simpler

```
def get_events(from_logic:, for_logic:, show_all: false)
  starts = eval(from_logic)
  finishes = eval(for_logic)

  if helpers.term_manager? || show_all
    object.events_between(starts, finishes).order(:starts_at)
  else
    helpers.current_user.term_events_between(object, starts, finishes).sort{ |x,y| x.starts_at <=> y.starts_at }
  end
end
```